# Compute Field not Getting Triggered in Odoo v8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to compute a value for a field and store the value in the DB. If I remove the `store=True` everything seems fine, but when I add the parameter instead of showing the result from the function I simply get a 0 in all my fields.

I also realized that my compute field function is not being called when I am on either the tree view or the form view.

My code looks like this:

```
@api.one
    def _compute_fats(self):

        for record in self:
            fats = 0
            fats_id = record.name.id
            get_detail = self.env['trackfood.foods'].search([['id', '=', fats_id],])
            for record2 in get_detail:
                fats = record2.fats

        self.fats = fats

fats = fields.Float(compute='_compute_fats', string="Fat" , store=True)
```

My whole objective is to grab the `fats` amount for each product and store it in the tracking table in order to be able to chart it.

Any tip will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try following,

```
@api.multi
def _compute_fats(self):
    for record in self:
        fats = 0
        fats_id = record.name.id
        get_detail = self.env['trackfood.foods'].search([['id', '=', fats_id],])
        for record2 in get_detail:
            fats = record2.fats

        record.fats = fats
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add a 'depends' definition to your method. The method will always (and only) be called whenever the value of any dependent field changes:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('name')        # seems to depend on record.name ??
def _compute_fats(self):
    for record in self:
        fats = 0
        fats_id = record.name.id     # Are you sure this is correct??
        get_detail = self.env['trackfood.foods'].browse([fats_id])   # Faster search by id
        for record2 in get_detail:
            fats = record2.fats

        record.fats = fats
```

Answer (score 1):

Use decorator multi and depends,

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('name')
def function_name(self):
    result= your_code
    self.fats = result
```